# How should I keep web service URL in mobile application?

Tags: web-services, mobile

I use Web API that hard coded URL within Mobile Application (Develop With Xamarin).

I'll change this variable and rebuild When i need to swap between Test environment and Production environment.

Is there any best practice related to how to keep service URL?
Or how can I change environment without rebuild an application?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add PRODUCTION and TEST as "Define Symbols" in Compiler tab for each target.

[image]

After than, You can use

```
string url = "";

#if PRODUCTION
url = "http://webpage.release
#endif

#if TEST
url = "http://webpage.test
#endif
```